# Can I suppress the Etag header from being issued on AWS Cloudfront?

Tags: http-headers, amazon-cloudfront

I am using Amazon's Cloudfront CDN for static assets. Couldfront issues an Etag for every GET request. I have set meta data fro all my assets with specific Cache-Control information, which (as I understand) makes the Etag superfluous. I test my site's load performance at WebPageTest.org, and it dings me for these unnecessary Etags. If they are in fact unnecessary, does anyone know of a way to suppress their being emitted?

Comment: Any update on this? ETag is forcing multiple get requests (even when Expires and max-age are set).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using an Origin Server and disabled ETag on the origin server, CloudFront would not add the ETag in its headers. I verified it by disabling the ETag on my origin server.

Comment: Is there any way to suppress Etag and Last-Modified when using CloudFront directly from S3?

Answer (score 0):

If Cloudfront delivers consistent Etags regardless of which node you download the asset from, then this should minimize the problem.  I've tested this by doing the following:

Resolving to Cloudfront from two different locations, I verified that the CNAMEs resolved to completely different sets of IP addresses.  The first server resolved to a set of 8 IP addresses in Amazon's LAX data center (lax1.cloudfront.net), the second server resolved to 8 IP addresses in Amazon's SFO datacenter (sfo4.cloudfront.net).

I selected an object in our Cloudfront distribution and did a "wget --server-response" from each location, and then compared the results.  I did this for each data center multiple times to get responses from different IP addresses in each datacenter.

The results were that the Etags were the same, regardles of which datacenter I hit, and which IP address responded from that datacenter.

I did notice that the following headers DID differ between servers
x-amz-id-2
x-amz-request-id
Age
X-Amz-Cf-Id
Via

Hope this helps,

David

[edited - removed comments on eTags based on good correction below]

Comment: This is just not true, web performance monitors bug you about Etag and Last-Modified headers because these two cause unnecessary round-trips to the server even when you have a very long max-age in Cache-Control header. If the Etag (and last-modified) are used correctly, the result of these round-trips would be status code 304. But the difference here is 300ms vs. 2ms (browser cache) and can accumulate if you use many static assets (css, js, images).

Answer (score 0):

## 2023 update

Amazon now supports adding/removing headers on a CloudFront distribution. [Announcement](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2023/01/amazon-cloudfront-supports-removal-response-headers/).

## How to setup

In my case, I wanted to remove the ETag for a particular URL pattern. So on AWS Console I went to my CloudFront Distribution and clicked the `Behaviors` tab and clicked `Create behavior`.

[image: Cache key and origin requests section of the Create behavior form]

In the `Cache key and origin requests` section, you can configure a `Response headers policy`. There is a link right below the field to create a new policy.

[image: Remove headers section of the Create response headers policy form]

In the `Create response headers policy` form, there is a `Remove headers` section in which you can specify all the headers you want removed. Add `ETag` and save it. Back to the `Create behavior` form, select your new policy under the `Custom` select group. Click the refresh button alongside the field to refresh the list if needed.

## Still getting 304?

ETag is not the only mechanism that can yield a 304. In my case, the clients were sending `If-Modified-Since`. You can remove the `Date` response header, but I don't particularly like that approach. Instead, I configured CloudFront to ignore the `If-Modified-Since` **request** header.

To do so, in the same `Cache key and origin requests` section, you can configure a `Origin request policy`.

[image: Origin request settings section]

For `Headers`, select the `All viewer headers except` and then configure which requests headers you want CloudFront to strip from the request before forwarding it to the origin (S3 in this case). I've added `If-Modified-Since` and `If-None-Match`.

However, if you use this approach, you'll have to set the `Cache policy` to `CachingDisabled` in the Behavior, otherwise your requests will not always reach the Origin (S3), thus it won't be effective to avoid the 304 status.

**Warning**: if your origin is a S3 bucket, you have to ignore the `Host` header if the bucket is not named after the custom domain reaching the CloudFront distribution (i.e.: `www.example.com`). Otherwise, you'll see the `The specified bucket does not exist` error for any request matching the Behavior you setup with this Origin request policy.

It is also worth to mention that you should consider using the correct caching headers in your Origin. There are few reasons to avoid returning a 304, as it speeds up everything and most clients will handle it nicely. I'd only consider this approach if your client is somewhat broken and you can't control it.